# Jammit, mhtml and the Vista IE7 bug

Tags: ruby, mhtml, jammit

So I'm going to start using data-uri's and mhtml to embed images in my stylesheets and i'm thinking of using [Jammit](https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit) to help me out there because it claims that it can generate data-uri and mhtml code for you

I know about the [IE7 Vista||Win7](http://www.phpied.com/the-proper-mhtml-syntax/) bug and that the fix is to close off the buondaries with a two dashes

If you look at the [example mhtml file](http://jashkenas.s3.amazonaws.com/misc/jammit_example/assets/silk-mhtml.css) provided in the [jammit docs](http://jashkenas.s3.amazonaws.com/misc/jammit_example/jammit.html) you might notice that they do not use the fix detailed above for the IE7 bug.

**Does Jammit handle the IE7 bug for you?** I have no way of testing IE7 so I'd just like to be sure of this before I got off and spend hours trying to get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's an IE7 bug. the Multipart MIME RFC ([1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) and its successors) clearly calls for the extra "--" at the end of the last boundary. I would consider it a Jammit bug.

Update: I checked the source, and it looks like they've fixed that bug. The example was generated before the fix.